# SSH to a computer on the same network

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I need to ssh onto a computer at my office, but am not sure how to go about it. I am on a Windows computer and want to access a Linux pc. How do I figure out the IP address of the Linux computer? Will I have to worry about SSH keys?

After obtaining the IP address, do I login to that computer with

```
ssh username@ip
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using Linux on VMware or VirtualBox?
To obtain your IP address in Linux

```
# ifconfig
```

And then, ssh from your terminal of Windows as

```
# ssh user@linux_ipaddress
```

You will be asked for the first time because of no-existence of ssh key

```
The authenticity of xxx
ECDSA key xxxx    
Are you sure you want to continue connecting(yes/no)
```

Just enter yes.
Of course, your Linux must start sshd and firewall (port 22) must open.